# How to send push notifications to iOS app installed on mdm?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am developing an iOS app which is distributed to users using MaaS360 MDM. Help me with leads on how to send push notifications to these devices?

P.S: I didn't find any IBM documentation for iOS push notifications in MaaS360.

Comment: Check this:  https://www.ibm.com/cloud/push-notifications/details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM MaaS360 doesn't have the ability to send applicative push notifications.

You'll have to use a third party push notification service like Firebase, or even the push notifications service on IBM Cloud.

P.S: You can use the MaaS360 configuration to push details to your NSUserDefaults for configuration purposes.

Comment: So, you mean I cannot directly send push notifications calling APNS api with device token ???

Comment: It is not done via MaaS360. It can be done with the push notification service on IBM Cloud.